# Get renered view from controller in Dispatch Event

Tags: zend-framework2

This is my EVENT_DISPATCH:

```
   public function preDispatch(MvcEvent $e) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget(); // The controller which is dispatched
        $request = $e->getRequest();
        $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();


        //$viewModel->
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $vars = $viewModel->getVariables();
            $vars['headers'] = $controller->layout();
            $view = new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel($vars);
            $e->setViewModel($view);
        } else {
            $controller->layout('ecik-light/layout');
        }
    }
```

I want render the controller view (without layout) to $var['html'] and get all headers (with header location).

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

use response

```
$e->getResponse()->getHeaders()
```